# MockInteractions tap on item doesn't select the item in web component tester

Tags: templates, polymer, polymer-1.0, wct

I have an element that populates a `<paper-menu>` with a `<template dom-repeat>`.

I want to test that once I add something in the `<paper-menu>`, I can select it and that it updates a property as expected.

```
<paper-menu id="customLabels" attr-for-selected="value" multi on-iron-select="updateCustomFilter" on-iron-deselect="updateCustomFilter">

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{customLabels}}">

    <paper-icon-item id="{{item.value}}" value$="{{item.value}}" role="menuitem">
      <iron-icon icon="label" item-icon style$="{{_setStyle(item.color)}}" invert"></iron-icon><span>{{item.value}}</span>
    </paper-icon-item>

  </template>

</paper-menu>

...

updateCustomFilter: function(){

  this.customFilter = this.$.customLabels.selectedValues;
  this.fire( 'custom-filter-changed');

},
```

I can not test the behavior properly. I want to mock a tap event on an item of the menu and ensure `custom-filter-changed` is fired.

If I select an element with `element.$.customLabels.select('red')`, the `custom-filter-changed` event is fired as expected.

If I select and element with `MockInteractions.tap( Polymer.dom( element.root ).querySelector( 'paper-icon-item[value="red"]' ) )`, the element gets taped (I hooked on-tap in the paper-item as a test) but element doesn't get selected.

I noticed that the tap event fired by MockInteractions.tap doesn't have target or srcElement and the path is different than if I actually click on the element.

I want to use `MockInteractions.tap` be mimic as closely as possible a real user action.

```
test('select custom label', function( done ){

  element.$.customLabels.addEventListener('dom-change', function( event ){

    element.addEventListener( 'custom-filter-changed', customFilterChanged );

    // MockInteractions.focus( Polymer.dom( element.root ).querySelector( 'paper-icon-item[value="red"]' ) );
    // MockInteractions.tap( Polymer.dom( element.root ).querySelector( 'paper-icon-item[value="red"]' ) );
    element.$.customLabels.select('red');

    element.$.customLabels.removeEventListener( 'dom-change', customFilterChanged );

  });


  // add element to the paper-menu
  element.customLabels = [{
    color: 'red',
    value: 'red'
  }];

  function customFilterChanged( event ) {

    assert.equal( element.customFilter.length, 1 );
    assert.equal( element.customFilter[0], 'red' );

    done();
    element.removeEventListener( 'custom-filter-changed', customFilterChanged );

  }

});
```